# pass php variables to javascript function error:missing ) after argument list

Tags: php, javascript, json

I try to use XMLHttpRequest() to post data to a url.
I wrote the following javascript:

```
function makePostRequest(url, params) {
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open("POST", url, true);
//Send the proper header information along with the request
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
    }
}
httpRequest.send(params);}
```

then i need to pass two php variables into this function in php file, one is a url, another is json data to be posted.

```
$url = "http://www.hello.com";
$json_str = "{\"format\": \"json\",
          \"event\": \"revert\",
      \"api_key\": \"$wgAPIKey\"}";

$editpage->editFormTextTop = 
          "<input type='button'value='hello' onclick='makePostRequest(\"$url\", \"$json_str\")' />";
```

After execution, i got the following error from firebug:

```
missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: does it tell you the line number?

Comment: "missing ) after argument list" seems like a JavaScript error, please try to find out (using Firebug or a similar tool) where exactly this error is  triggered; please also post the generated JSON-string, as returned by your script;

Comment: Where is `$encoded_params` defined and where is `$json_str` used?

Comment: sorry, it'S a transcription error. i updated it. it should be $json_str

Comment: @feeela error:"missing ) after argument list" is from firebug.

Comment: @sijitang: see my answer below, it should help you fix your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I suggest. To clean up the code, let's removed the embedded onclick and give it an ID:

```
$editpage->editFormTextTop = "<input type='button' id="requestBtn" />";
```

Now in the head of your script you can initialize the values;

**Note:** This code is simplified

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   var url = "http://www.hello.com";
   var jsonString = "{\"format\": \"json\",\"event\": \"revert\",\"api_key\": \"<?php echo $wgAPIKey ?>\"}";
   // now we can assign the function to the button
   document.getElementById("requestBtn").onclick = function () {
      makePostRequest(url,json_string);
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your second block of code has a transcription error, and that the "$encoded_params" PHP variable is supposed to be "$json_str". When that variable is expanded into the HTML for that `<input>` element, the double quote characters in it will result in an error, because the input element will look like this:

```
<input type='button'value='hello' onclick='makePostRequest("http://www.hello.com", "{"format": "json", "event": "revert", "api_key": "something"}")' />
```

See how that call to "makePostRequest()" is messed up?  The "encoded_params" string, with its own embedded double-quote characters, ends up being a malformed string constant.

Comment: sorry, there is no $encoded_params, you are right, it should be $json_str.

Answer (score 0):

Your title and content text don't match. If you want to pass php variable to javascript simply do

`var yourvar = '<?php echo $your_php_var; ?>';`